# C#: The result of casting a negative integer to a byte

Tags: c#

I was a looking at the source code of [a project](https://github.com/Zyphrax/pixelcryptor), and I noticed the following [statement](https://github.com/Zyphrax/pixelcryptor/blob/master/PixelCryptor.Core/Coding/CoderSeal.cs) (both keyByte and codedByte are of type `byte`):

```
return (byte)(keyByte - codedByte);
```

I'm trying now to understand what would the result be in cases where keyByte is smaller than codedByte, which results in a negative integer.

After some experiments to understand the result of casting a negative integer which has a value in the range [-255 : -1], I got the following results:

```
byte result = (byte) (-6);  // result = 250
byte result = (byte) (-50); // result = 206
byte result = (byte) (-17); // result = 239
byte result = (byte) (-20); // result = 236
```

So, provided that `-256 < a < 0` , I was able to determine the result by:

```
result = 256 + a;
```

My question is: should I always expect this to be the case?

Comment: to repeat: you're absolutely correct.  Because any "negative" value is outside the domain of a .Net "byte", .Net will first promote (to an integral value larger than 255).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that will always be the case (i.e. it is not simply dependent on your environment or compiler, but is defined as part of the C# language spec).  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691349(v=vs.71).aspx:

> In an `unchecked` context, the result is truncated by discarding any high-order bits that do not fit in the destination type.

The next question is, if you take away the high-order bits of a negative `int` between -256 and -1, and read it as a byte, what do you get?  This is what you've already discovered through experimentation: it is 256 + x.

Note that endianness does not matter because we're discarding the high-order (or most significant) bits, not the "first" 24 bits.  So regardless of which end we took it from, we're left with the least significant byte that made up that int.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what if your hardware (CPU) uses anything other than two's complement binary representation of integers?  To get an answer to this we need to go to the CLR spec rather than the C# spec.  ECMA335, Section 12.1, identifies `int` as being "32-bit two‘s-complement signed value".  That's all just theory with the limited range of hardware on which .NET (or mono) currently runs, but it's the ultimate answer to the question we have been asked.  Yes, negative values cannot give any numerically different results, not even on hypothetical future hardware.

Comment: Out of curiousity, what if the dinosaurs never became extinct?  Would we fly pterodactyls instead of inventing jet planes?  Why not just give Mota credit for the simple fact that this is absolutely and totally correct: `for any .Net language, for signed integral values -256 < a < 0: result = 256 + a;`

Comment: One more reference for the nonce: [There is a predefined implicit conversion from byte to short, ushort, int, uint, long, ulong, float, double, or decimal.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bdb6693%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

Yes.  Remember, there's no such thing as "-" in the domain of a .Net "Byte":

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2ayt412.aspx
>
> Because Byte is an unsigned type, it cannot represent a negative
>   number. If you use the unary minus (-) operator on an expression that
>   evaluates to type Byte, Visual Basic converts the expression to Short
>   first. (Note: substitute any CLR/.Net language for "Visual Basic")

ADDENDUM:
Here's a sample app:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace TestByte
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int i = -255; i < 256; i++)
            {
                byte b = (byte)i;
                System.Console.WriteLine("i={0}, b={1}", i, b);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the resulting output:

```
testbyte|more
i=-255, b=1
i=-254, b=2
i=-253, b=3
i=-252, b=4
i=-251, b=5
...
i=-2, b=254
i=-1, b=255
i=0, b=0
i=1, b=1
...
i=254, b=254
i=255, b=255
```

Comment: I downvoted this because it doesn't address his concern - namely, whether the casting of a negative integer to byte will always be the same.  It's nice to know, but entirely separate, that if you say `-b`, where `b` is a `byte`, it will convert that to a `short` first.

Comment: Can you give a reference?  ECMA 334 (14.7) seems to only recognize arithmetics on `int`, `uint`, `long`, `ulong`.  Not that it is very relevant here, but one of us is wrong in the details and I'm curious who that is.

Comment: I have no idea what Visual Basic does, but that is not what the C# spec says in section 4.5.1: "For the unary – operator, the operand is converted to type T, where T is the first of int and long that can fully represent all possible values of the operand." In this case that type is int. Also, binary - converts to int as well for byte.

Comment: @mikez - I'm basically saying that VB.NET can't do that either because CLR does not have 16 bit arithmetics.

Comment: @JirkaHanika Just because the clr does not support 16 bit arithmetic does not mean that VB cannot convert Byte to Short with a unary minus operator. This is in fact what it does. However, c# does not do this as it says in the spec.

Comment: @mikez - Thanks.  I stand corrected.  I now understand this blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2004/02/02/66345.aspx  to imply that the CIL sub instruction can only take 4byte or 8byte arguments, but that VB.NET uses 4byte subtraction to simulate 2byte arithmetics, even with binary minus (unlike C#).

Answer (score 3):

Here is an algorithm that performs the same logic as casting to byte, to help you understand it:

For positives:

```
byte bNum = iNum % 256;
```

For negatives:

```
byte bNum = 256 + (iNum % 256);
```

It's like searching for any `k` which causes `x + 255k` to be in the range `0 ... 255`. There could only be one `k` which produces a result with that range, and the result will be the result of casting to byte.

Another way of looking at it is as if it "cycles around the byte value range":

Lets use the `iNum = -712` again, and define a `bNum = 0`.

We shall do `iNum++; bNum--;` untill `iNum == 0`:

```
iNum = -712;
bNum = 0;

iNum++; // -711
bNum--; // 255 (cycles to the maximum value)

iNum++; // -710
bNum--; // 254

... // And so on, as if the iNum value is being *consumed* within the byte value range cycle.
```

This is, of course, just an illustration to see how logically it works.

Answer (score 0):

This is what happens in `unchecked` context. You could say that the runtime (or compiler if the `Int32` that you cast to `Byte` is known at compiletime) adds or subtracts 256 as many times as is needed until it finds a representable value.

In a `checked` context, an exception (or compiletime error) results. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/khy08726.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes - unless you get an exception.

.NET defines all arithmetic operations only on 4 byte and larger data types.  So the only non-obvious point is how converting an `int` to a `byte` works.

For a conversion from an integral type to another integral type, the result of conversion depends on overflow checking context (says the ECMA 334 standard, Section 13.2.1).

So, in the following context

```
checked
{
    return (byte)(keyByte - codedByte);
}
```

you will see a `System.OverflowException`.  Whereas in the following context:

```
unchecked
{
    return (byte)(keyByte - codedByte);
}
```

you are guaranteed to always see the results that you expect regardless of whether you do or don't add a multiple of 256 to the difference; for example, 2 - 255 = 3.

This is true regardless of how the **hardware** [represents signed values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations).  The CLR standard (ECMA 335) specifies, in Section 12.1, that the `Int32` type is a "32-bit two's-complement signed value".  (Well, that also matches all platforms on which .NET or mono is currently available anyway, so one could almost guess that it would work anyway, but it is good to know that the practice is supported by the language standard and portable.)

Some teams do not want to specify overflow checking contexts explicitly, because they have a policy of checking for overflows early in development cycle, but not in released code.  In these cases you can safely do byte arithmetic like this:

```
return (byte)((keyByte - codedByte) % 256);
```